# how to write Powershell script to identify any azure resource with a creation date in the last 30 days in multiple subscriptions

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

how to identify all azure resources with a creation date in the last 30 days in multiple subscriptions using PowerShell script

Comment: Show what you have tried and what's the problem, Stackoverflow is not a free coding website.

Comment: @Joy Wang yeah i knew that its now free coding website. Please find the below query which i have written. Now i have to convert this query to get multiple subscription resources.

Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "<ResourceGroupName>" | Where-Object {$_.Timestamp -gt '12/15/2020'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first you should note what you are using is a really old `AzureRm` module command, it was deprecated and will not be updated. So I recommend you to use the new [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-5.3.0) module, you could refer to the doc to [migrate Azure PowerShell from AzureRM to Az](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-5.3.0).

Then use the script below, it will get all the resources from all the subscriptions your logged user account/service principals can access.

```
$subs= Get-AzSubscription
foreach($sub in $subs){
    Set-AzContext -Subscription $sub.Id -Tenant $sub.TenantId
    Write-Host "login to subscription - "$sub.Name
    $groups = (Get-AzResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName
    foreach($group in $groups){
        Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $group | Where-Object {$_.Timestamp -gt '12/15/2020'}
    }
}
```

---

If you still want to use the old `AzureRm` module, then the script should be:

```
$subs= Get-AzureRmSubscription
foreach($sub in $subs){
    Set-AzureRmContext -Subscription $sub.Id -Tenant $sub.TenantId
    Write-Host "login to subscription - "$sub.Name
    $groups = (Get-AzureRmResourceGroup).ResourceGroupName
    foreach($group in $groups){
        Get-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName $group | Where-Object {$_.Timestamp -gt '12/15/2020'}
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, i would like to use Az module. let me try this code and come back to you Joy.